# Anchor Link to Target Inside Fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, fieldset

I am linking to sections on the page that are inside collapsed fieldsets.

When a user clicks this link, I want to scroll down the page and open the fieldset to show the content.

I have all the scrolling set up, and it works until I hide the target inside a collapsed fieldset, then functionality breaks.

```
<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>

<fieldset class="collapsed">
  <div id="section1">
   ..content
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

And then my jQuery for scrolling...

```
(function ($) {
        var $root = $('html, body');
        $('a').click(function() {
            var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
            $root.animate({
                scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
            }, 500, function () {
                window.location.hash = href;
            });
            return false;
        });
    }(jQuery));
```

How do I get the click on the anchor to open the fieldset, and then scroll down to it?

Comment: I don't see where you're expanding the fieldset in there. You'd do that first, then the other stuff in a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `<legend>` element inside the `<fieldset>` and target the `<legend>` as `#section1`.

Add this to jQuery to toggle the class `.collapsed` and `.expanded`:

```
var exp = $(href).parent();
exp.toggleClass('collapsed', 'expanded');
```

You need to use CSS as well to create the `.collapsed` and `.expanded` states:

```
.collapsed {
  height: 0;
  border: none;
}
.expanded {
  height: 300px;
}
#section1 {
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #000;
  color: #fc2;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}
.collapsed > .content {
  font: 400 0/0 'Verdana';
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  font: 400 16px/1.4 'Verdana';
}
```

The HTML is modified so you can click the `<legend>` of the `<fieldset>` and toggle `.collapsed` and `.expanded` as well.

```
<fieldset class="collapsed">
    <legend id="section1"><a href="#section1">Heading</a></legend>
    <div class="content">
    ..content XXXXX xxxxxxxxxxxnnnnnnnnnnnnn hbyigyugvyibrgh fwgewg wefgeh bbbbb uhuhouihoijpiok erhtru efwgwrhnj
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Snippet**

```js
(function($) {
  var $root = $('html, body');
  $('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
      scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function() {
      window.location.hash = href;
    });
    var exp = $(href).parent();
    exp.toggleClass('collapsed', 'expanded');

    return false;
  });

}(jQuery));
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.4 'Verdana';
}
fieldset {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
legend {
  margin-top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
a {
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.collapsed {
  height: 0;
  border: none;
}
.expanded {
  height: 300px;
}
#section1 {
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #000;
  color: #fc2;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}
.collapsed > .content {
  font: 400 0/0 'Verdana';
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  font: 400 16px/1.4 'Verdana';
}
.spacer {
  height: 700px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>



<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>

<!--For demo-->
<div class="spacer"></div>

<fieldset class="collapsed">
  <legend id="section1"><a href="#section1">Heading</a></legend>
  <div class="content">
    ..content XXXXX xxxxxxxxxxxnnnnnnnnnnnnn hbyigyugvyibrgh fwgewg wefgeh bbbbb uhuhouihoijpiok erhtru efwgwrhnj
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

`(function ($) {
        var $root = $('html, body');
        $('a').click(function() {
            var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
            $(href).parent().show(); //updated line
            $root.animate({
                scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
            }, 500, function () {
                window.location.hash = href;
            });
            return false;
        });
    }(jQuery));`

Just made a simple change. Which you can see on, commented line above.